# Authenticating users (using both Firebase and Google authentication) on Cloud Endpoints and API Explorer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, google-authentication

Using `Cloud Endpoints Frameworks` for App Engine I've added authenticating with Firebase Auth in addition to authenticating with Google Accounts.

All is good and well, I can authorize client requests using Firebase Auth, but now I can no longer use `API Explorer` since that uses Google's authentication and results in a `401 "Invalid credentials"` response.

I added `Firebase Auth` by doing:

```java
    @Api(
            name = "test",
            version = "v1",
//        authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
            issuers = {
                    @ApiIssuer(
                            name = "firebase",
                            issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/PROJECT-ID",
                            jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
            },
            issuerAudiences = {
                    @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "PROJECT-ID")
            },
            scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
            clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER},
            audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
            namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "XXX", ownerName = "XXX", packagePath="")
    )
```

A method that works with Google authentication and `API Explorer` is:

```
@ApiMethod(
)
public User getTestUserGoogle(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    return user;
}
```

And a method that works with `Firebase Auth` but not OAuth 2.0 on `API Explorer`  is:

```
@ApiMethod(
        authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class}
)
public User getTestUserFirebase(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    return user;
}
```

This code snippet seems to suggest `EspAuthenticator.class` shoud work with Google authentication: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend/src/main/java/com/example/echo/Echo.java#L128

However the API Explorer request fails with a `401 "Invalid credentials"` response whenever `EspAuthenticator.class` is set as the authenticator.

Is there any way I can get both Google and Firebase authentication to work on the same method? The only difference between those 2 methods is `EspAuthenticator.class` and based on the official code snippet in the link above it looks like Google authentication should still work with the `EspAuthenticator.class` authenticator.

---

Update:
The error I get from Stackdriver is:

> com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator authenticate:
>   Authentication failed:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   com.google.api.auth.UnauthenticatedException:
>   org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException: Unable to process JOSE
>   object (cause: org.jose4j.lang.JoseException: Invalid JOSE Compact
>   Serialization. Expecting either 3 or 5 parts for JWS or JWE
>   respectively but was 2.):
>   ya29.GmAkBDwfsFuyOCL7kqSSLelSHpOb9LJLyewtPfpeH1a4t12i8MWmzHBNliMeR9dAtOSARG2o-QlZEHisfEPYbA-Wb-Eh36zugIufmVbDe4E2TP9StAOjub8nsrhAzuGbolE
>   (EspAuthenticator.java:86)

Also filed an issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either add `GoogleOAuth2Authenticator` or `EndpointsAuthenticator`

`EndpointsAuthenticator` is a wrapper for `GoogleJwtAuthenticator`, `GoogleAppEngineAuthenticator`, `GoogleOAuth2Authenticator`.

well, your `authenticators` parameter is supposed to look like

```
authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class, GoogleOAuth2Authenticator.class},
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think anyone would come through, but it worked! For a user that hasn't had any posts but has been a member for 3 years, you're like my guardian angel dude. Thank you, I definitely don't think it would have been easy for me to figure that out. 

For requests authenticated using GoogleOAuth2Authenticator, I am still obviously getting the same warning logs posted above from EspAuthenticator. Any way around that?

Also any idea how the sample code on  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ seems to use EspAuthenticator for Google authentication?

Comment: `EspAuthenticator` works with JWT tokens only. Warnings appears because `EspAuthenticator` doesn’t validate token type and try to parse OAuth token as a JWT token, but GoogleOAuth2Authenticator does this check.
To avoid warnings just change authenticators order
`authenticators = {GoogleOAuth2Authenticator.class, EspAuthenticator.class}`

Answer (score 0):

It's more simple, you need pass token to appengine.

Once you have the firebase token you have to auth with [JSON Web Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) I believe this is the EspAuthenticator.class method.

Here is the Authentication using firebase token

### Auth JSON WEB TOKEN Firebase Users

```
curl \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${firebase_token}" \
 -X GET \
 "https://$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/firebase_user"
```